# .NET Core + WCF integration with DI Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf

I have an problem to declare dependency injection. I have to declare a WCF service and I did it like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceClient>();
```

As I will need to work with the WCF header I need to add a behavior to check the headers. Normally I would do it like this:

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add( new HeaderInspectionBehavior());
```

But I can't do it that way because I'm getting the `IService` injected in the constructor.

I tried to do it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672518/making-wcf-operationcontext-play-nicely-with-di-and-testing) way:

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new HeaderInspectionBehavior());
services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceClient>(sp => client);
```

But it didn't work, in the second WCF call it changes the state to "FAULT" or "CLOSED".

Does anyone know of another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based in [this](https://fulviocanducci.medium.com/inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncias-asp-net-core-baa3bc1ea9c9) i found a solution that looks like this:

```
ServiceClient Config(IServiceProvider _) => new ServiceClient(..., ...);
services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceClient>(Config);
```

It's work for me.